# What does AWK define as columns

Tags: awk

I'm working with a file that has multiple entries looking like this:

```
name //filenameanddirectory score 0000000000000000000000000000100000000000001000000100000000000001000000100000010001011000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000001000000000000000000000000000100000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010100001010000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.107955
```

I need to retrieve only entries which have a certain value in the long 01 entry, I tried the command

```
awk '{if (substr($5,20,1)==1) printf "%s %s %.3f %.4f %s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5} inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

unfortunately i don't get any results, does anybody know what might cause the problem?

Comment: whitespace is a column separator, so `name` is one column, `//filenameanddirectory` is another, etc...

Comment: Field `$5` is the `0.107955` field.

Comment: What is the "certain value" that you are looking for?

Comment: Awk defines whatever you want as columns, as @MarcB said though whitespace is default

Comment: Do any of the filename and directory elements contain spaces?

Comment: How do you think the `%.3f` specifier will format the string "score"?

Answer (score 1):

In awk fields are by default  separated by whitespace sequences (spaces, TABs, and newlines) and thus columns are defined . The value between two consecutive field separator is taken a column . 
if you explicitly want to define field separator it can be done by setting FS in awk .

Comment: +1. the `-F` flag lets you define the field separator as well.